# Fragment caching & CSRF

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the prefered way to deal with cached forms and CSRF token? [Here](https://coderwall.com/p/0sctaa/forms-csrf-authenticity-token-and-fragment-caching-in-rails) they propose a JS overwrite of input attribute, but I also want to cache the header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an article describing different methods: http://www.fastly.com/blog/Caching-the-Uncacheable-CSRF-security/.

**A short summary:**

1. Using ESI (Edge Side Includes): render a placeholder in Rails which you fill with the CSRF token later.
2. Including the CSRF token in a cookie and copy it into the form via javascript.
3. Fetch the token in a separate AJAX request and copy it into the form via javascript.

**My take:**

You need to set up special infrastructure for using ESI, so I do not like that solution. AJAX requests are slow and a lot of network overhead, so I do not like that solution as well...
So I would go with the cookie solution or with the JS solution you already mentioned, since these are the simplest solutions.

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that by default rails will be inserting a hidden field in all your forms that includes the CSRF token. This form will still be cached. Although the invalid token errors will go away, you are leaking your users' tokens to other users in this cache.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me. I just kept this in my `application.js` and everything work flawlessly.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
       var csrf_value = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
       xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", csrf_value );
     },
  });
```